# auto indentation on common lisp emacs + slime + sbcl in windows

Tags: windows, lisp, common-lisp, slime, sbcl

I can't use auto indentation function on emacs + slime + sbcl when I define my function and so on.

My `.emacs` file configuration is this:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program
"D:/emacs/sbcl_1.0.37/sbcl.exe"
      lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function
      slime-complete-symbol-function 'slime-fuzzy-complete-symbol
      slime-startup-animation nil
      slime-enable-evaluate-in-emacs t
      slime-log-events t
      slime-outline-mode-in-events-buffer nil
      slime-repl-return-behaviour :send-only-if-after-complete
      slime-autodoc-use-multiline-p t
      slime-highlight-compiler-notes t)

(add-to-list 'load-path
 "d:/emacs/site-lisp/slime")  ; your SLIME directory
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slime section in my `.emacs`:

```
;;; SLIME
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime)
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
(global-set-key "\C-cs" 'slime-selector)
```

Comment: Wow, it's working by adding '(slime-fancy). Thank you very much Svante! and Rainer for correcting my sentences.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Which function should TAB be bound to? I think YASnippet is overriding some Slime-function for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using emacs 24.1 with slime and discovered that using

```
(require 'slime)
```

with

```
(require 'slime-autoloads)
```

would not allow slime setup to work, ie no slime-repl or other slime-fancy features would load.

Once I removed

```
(require 'slime)
```

it all worked fine.